# Sending PHP mail

Tags: php, sendmail

I would like to send this email.

I have seen configuration but not sure what to do or make any heads or tails out of them. The mail would be sent from my PC right now.

Error I get is - Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\send.php on line 165.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-php-send-email-via-smtp-authentication.html
http://forums.devshed.com/mail-server-help-111/how-to-set-up-php-ini-to-send-mail-from-106329.html

Looked on these two sites from google search but don't acutally understand it. Can some help me please.

Comment: I cant send anything. The error I get is - Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\send.php on line 165.

Comment: Do you have a mail server installed?

Comment: I havent installed anything. Im learning bit by bit, all I need is mail server?

Comment: `$to = will@hotmail.com;`?! Where are your quotes young man?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to send mail from your localhost (Your PC) It's not setup to send mail. Move the script to a production server and it will work

Comment: So once I have moved my code to a working server, everything should be sending? Is that what your saying? Because later when my code is complete, it will be moved but it is working in progress right now.

Comment: Yep, it should work just fine. Your localhost won't always work exactly as a real production server. This is one of those examples

Comment: Thank you very much. If I wanted to test it, what would I need to install to make it work?

Comment: Give this a shot. I haven't tried this tutorial, but after glancing at it, it seems right. http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a mail server installed. You have a few options:

1. Install a mail server such as Postfix or sendmail
2. Connect to an existing SMTP server, for example through Gmail. (See: [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page))